# FullSimplify, TransformationFunctions, Assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I make Mathematica consider Assumptions in FullSimplify also when applying custom Transformation Functions?

It works with the Automatic Transformation Functions:

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[a^2], a < 0]
-a
FullSimplify[a < 0, a < 0]
True
```

It does not work with custom Transformation Functions:

custom Transformation function replacing negative terms by pi:

```
tf2[e_] := e /. a__ /; a < 0 -> π
```

custom complexity function making pi as a result attractive:

```
myCount = (-Count[#, π, {0, Infinity}]) &;


mySimplify = (FullSimplify[#, a < 0, TransformationFunctions -> {tf2},
      ComplexityFunction -> myCount]) &;
```

This works for numbers

```
mySimplify[1]
```

> `1`

```
mySimplify[-3]
```

> `π`

It does however not consider the assumption that a<0

```
mySimplify[a]
```

> `a`

Comment: A bit hacky, but you could do `tf2[e_] := 
 e /. {a__ /; ToCharacterCode[ToString@a] == {97} -> Pi, 
   a__ /; a < 0 -> Pi}` I don't know why your example doesn't work though.

Comment: O.k., but a is just an example, I want to match more complex terms later.

Comment: I think it's a matter of mistaking how much assumptions is willing to do. After all `Assuming[a < 0, TrueQ[a < 0]]` doesn't  work, and `/;` tests the truth of a condition.

Comment: Your `tf2` is not using any function using assumptions. Try `tf2[e_] := e /. a_ /; Refine[a < 0] -> \[Pi]` and `mySimplify = 
  Assuming[a < 0, 
    FullSimplify[#, TransformationFunctions -> {tf2}, 
     ComplexityFunction -> myCount]] &;`.